# Angular 1.2 $q breaks when returning $q.promise several times (different conditions) within same function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.model.initJobs = function(forceLoad){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var companyId = authService.getCompanyId();
    if(!Boolean(companyId) || companyId == 'undefined'){//no data was loaded yet - bummer
        deferred.resolve([]);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    var jobs = jobsService.getJobs(companyId);
    if(jobs && !forceLoad){
        deferred.resolve(jobs);
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    $scope.__loading = true;
    jobsService.getCompanyJobs(companyId).then(function(data){
        $scope.__loading = false;
        jobsService.setJobs(data.data, companyId);
        deferred.resolve(data.data);
    },
    function(errorData){
        $scope.__loading = false;
        $location.path('/notfound');
        jobsService.setJobs([], companyId)//those line are a precuation
        deferred.resolve(data.data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

 $scope.model.initJobs(true).then(function(data){
      $scope.model.jobs = data;
  });
```

The following freezes the screen with Angular 1.2.0 and 1.2.1, is it because I am returning the defrred.promise on several occasions within the same function?.
The idea here is not to load the data again if I already have it stored within my service.

Any thoughts?.
Any help is appreciated & welcome.

EDIT:
I should perhaps mention that ht above works perfectly fine on AngularJS 1.0.8!

Comment: logic doesn't make sense. If no data loaded you resolve `deffered` and immediately return `promise`....nothing else will happen. Show code for `authService.getCompanyId()`

Comment: You probably want to `reject` the promise in the `error` function instead of resolving it. However, that would not cause a frozen screen. Are there any errors on the console? Which browser/platform as you using?

Comment: Personally I think you want the various services to resolve their own promises and when those resolve, resolve the `initJobs`. Hard to tell without more code... a demo would help

Comment: Are `setJobs` and `getJobs` syncronized?

Comment: Simple getter method, this is a precaution because I need to use the companyId in the REQUEST FOR THE JOBS THAT SENT TO THE rest resource, this won't happen since I resolve the request that gives the companyId prior the routeProvider

Comment: @MaximShoustin getJobs() and setJobs() are simple getter and setter methods, thus they are synchronous

Comment: @charlietfl everything works perfectly fine with angular 1.0.8, no problems in logic whatsoever

Comment: suggest creating a demo

Comment: Like a plunk\jsfiddle perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

You are making it way harder than it needs to be, generally you never need deferreds.

```
$scope.model.initJobs = function (forceLoad) {
    var companyId = authService.getCompanyId();
    if (!Boolean(companyId) || companyId == 'undefined') { //no data was loaded yet - bummer
        return $q.resolve([]);
    }
    var jobs = jobsService.getJobs(companyId);
    if (jobs && !forceLoad) {
        return $q.resolve(jobs);
    }

    $scope.__loading = true;
    return jobsService.getCompanyJobs(companyId)
    .then(function (data) {
        jobsService.setJobs(data.data, companyId);
        return data.data;
    })
    .catch(function (errorData) {
        $location.path('/notfound');
        jobsService.setJobs([], companyId) //those line are a precuation
        //You seem not have tested because this won't work
        return data.data;
    })
    .finally(function() {
         $scope.__loading = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: I will try this code along with the latest Angular production version and will keep you posted.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately, did throw a bunch of error though :(.
As to the origin of my issues, I'm still clueless.

Comment: Errors say that there is no a method called then nor a method called catch.
SOmething's wierd

Comment: @OlegTikhonov `getCompanyJobs` doesn't return a promise then